# Images in gridview shuffles after scrolling using Glide library

Tags: android, image, gridview, scroll, android-glide

I am using glide library to display images in grid view but when I scroll the images in grid view, the images change dynamically every time. Having wrong images at the positions. 
Here is my Adapter code:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private String[] imageUrls;

public ImageView image;
public TextView text;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
        super(context, R.layout.image_grid_layout, imageUrls);
        this.context = context;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (null == convertView) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_grid_layout, parent, false);
            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        }

        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(imageUrls[position])
                .into(image);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```